# Index with accented letters

Tags: math-mode, characters, accents

I'm trying to typeset the following

```
$Q_å=l_å \cdot m$
```

But LaTeX won't typeset these special or accented letters in my document!
Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: please provide a MWE; it seems to be related to the missing input encoding definition

Answer (score 3):

Names for accents change in math mode, so you should use `\mathring a` as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$Q_{\mathring a}=l_{\mathring a} \cdot m$

\end{document}
```

See [the comprehensive list of symbols](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive) Table 164 for the other accent commands.  Changing input encoding usually does not help for this situation.

*ADDITION* If your text italics and math italics agree, which is the case by default but may well change if a font package is loaded, then you can implement @daelif's suggestion as follows:

[image: Sample output 2]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$Q_{\textnormal{\itshape å}}=l_{\textnormal{\itshape å}} \cdot m$

\end{document}
```

I have used `\textnormal` to negate any formatting from the surrounding text, `inputenc` to enable input of `å` directly, `fontenc` to ensure a font with a good glyph, and `mathtools` to ensure the size of the subscript is appropriate.

Comment: why not get the real å? (`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` might be needed) `Q_{\textit{\aa}}`, then it will be a correctly placed accent and not a composed symbol

Comment: Ahh, great!And thankyou very much for such a fast answer!
/Johan

Comment: @daleif That will work nicely provided the text font italic matches  math italic, which might not be the case if a font package has been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on using these accents in `math-mode` you should use the `\accents` package. For this specific example, you would use:

```
$Q_{\accentset{\circ}{a}}=l_{\accentset{\circ}{a}} \cdot m$
```

which would output:

[image: accents output]

The accents package is very useful and is well documented (see: [CTAN - Accents Package](http://www.http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bezos))

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        Q_å=l_å \cdot m
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
        Q_{\mathring{a}}=l_{\mathring{a}} \cdot m
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]